# Rails arel query for matching multiple habtm records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many, arel

I have a setup as follows,

```
Post
- has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

Tag
- has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

> I want to find all the posts which have `social`, `informative` tags
>   in it, I can also use their ID's suppose `1` and `2`. Using arel or ActiveRecord or plain SQL.

I can find `posts` having `any` tags using:
`post_tags[:tag_id].in([1, 2])`

I can find `posts` having `none` tags using:
`post_tags[:tag_id].not_in([1, 2])`

But I can't do: 
`post_tags[:tag_id].in_all([1, 2])`
that's because one record cannot match all the tag ID's ever.

How could I do this?

Comment: Maybe what you’re looking for is the `include` or `eq` methods?

Comment: @Fagundes cant do that, `post_tags[:tag_id].eq(1).and(post_tags[:tag_id].eq(2))` wont work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

```
posts = Arel::Table.new(:posts)
posts_tags = Arel::Table.new(:posts_tags)

tag_ids = [1, 2]

ids_predicate = 
  posts.
    project(posts[:id]).
    join(posts_tags).on(
      posts[:id].eq(posts_tags[:post_id])
    ).
    where(
      posts_tags[:tag_id].in(tag_ids)
    ).
    group(posts[:id]).
    having(
      posts_tags[:tag_id].count.eq(tag_ids.count)
    )


Post.where(posts[:id].in(ids_predicate))
```

Pretty cool I think!